# Is there a Javascript equivalent for Python's "u" Unicode prefix?

Tags: javascript, python, unicode

I have a string that could look something like this: `\u1234hello\u1234\u1234`. I'd like to convert all the Unicode fragments of the string into their actual characters.

In Python, I'd just stick a `u` beforehand to specify that it's a [Unicode string](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings) but how can I do this in Javascript?

Cheers

Gausie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript, all strings are Unicode. No `u` prefix is necessary, and all `\u` escapes will be recognized.

Comment: UCS-2  or UTF-16? The page you link to says either is fine, but your mention of characters outside the BMP only makes sense for UTF-16.

Comment: @delnan: Oh? Then I'm not sure.

Comment: Extra-BMP support is dependent on the JavaScript engine itself.